# Why is there an alternative download page of python for China?

Tags: python, legal

On http://python.org there are two download pages, http://python.org/download/ for international users and http://python.org/getit/ for Chinese users.

When accessed from a country other than china, the second link redirects to the normal download page.

Why is that so?

Comment: Not being in China, I cannot verify this. You can ask the team at webmaster@python.org.

Comment: one crazy explanation would be that 2.6.4 (June 4 1989 protests http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiananmen_Square_protests_of_1989) isn't allowed to be downloaded in China. http://posted-stuff.blogspot.ro/2010/07/downloading-python-from-china-or-not.html

Comment: Isn’t this a bit far-fetched? :)

Comment: The [site source code](https://svn.python.org/www/trunk/beta.python.org/) offers no clues.

Comment: [Great Firewall of China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China) aka "Golden Shield Project" might relate - _"a censorship and surveillance project operated by the Ministry of Public Security (MPS) division of the government of China... The access to a certain IP address is denied. If the target Web site is hosted in a shared hosting server, all Web sites on the same server will be blocked. This affects all IP protocols (mostly TCP) such as HTTP, FTP or POP. A typical circumvention method is to find proxies..."_

Comment: But if the IP of python.org was blocked it would make no sense to link from it do a separate download page, would it?

Comment: @Profpatsch You are assuming all of python.org is under the same IP. There's no technical reason for that... Also, the GFC may selectively block urls, it doesn't just block an IP or an IP range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As people have correctly guessed in the comments, the [Great Firewall of China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China) is to blame here. Martin v. Loewis clarifies this in [Python-list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list), Python's general discussion list:

> It's intentional. Notice that it goes to a different URL than the English download link.
>
> > Which is a synonym for the English download link (/getit is /download at present)
> >     Perhaps a translated page is planned?
>
> No, translation is not the motivation at all.
>
> > Chinese readers will know when to use it.
> >
> > Why a special link just for Chinese and not several other languages?
>
> Because only Chinese users may have to bypass URL filters that selectively censor content from python.org. Let's see how long censors need to pick up this discussion and ban more of Python across the Great Firewall :-(
>
> Regards,
>   Martin

<sub>Source: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-March/599359.html</sub>

The `/getit` url seems more like a proactive measure than anything else. If it gets blocked, then all python.org's administrators need to do is create another url for their Chinese users, without affecting any of their other users. Until of course the Chinese censors decide to block all of python.org. `</sigh>`

Comment: @Profpatsch You are welcome. The Chinese censors are known to be very unpredictable and at times quite moronic (at least from a non Chinese point of view). Not so long ago they blocked Bitbucket, breaking quite a few open source projects' download pages in the process (what's more natural than linking to your source repository from your download page?), including PyPy's. When dealing with such crap, a few proactive measures are unfortunately necessary.

Comment: Bitbucket is blocked? I'm guessing GitHub as well...? (too lazy to search from mobile.. Sorry Yanni.. :)

Comment: @Lipis It was blocked for a few months, not sure if it still is.